# How to use the same random number several times?

Tags: variable, random

I'm using the `xfp` package to create a random number and defined the following command

```
\newcommand{\unif}{\fpeval{randint(1,10)}}
```

How can I assign a random number to a variable such that I can use this specific random number several times, i.e. drawing a point (with pstricks) (x,f(x)) where x is random but should be fixed for calculating f(x).

Comment: `\edef\unif{\fpeval{randint(1,10)}}` then it will be evaluated at definition time

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Old McDonald had a random, EIEIO.  With `\unifinit`, the remembered number `\unif` can be (re)initialized.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\newcommand\unifinit{\edef\unif{\fpeval{randint(1,10)}}}
\begin{document}

\unifinit

With a \unif, \unif{} here and a \unif, \unif{} there\\
\unif, \unif; \unif, \unif,\\
everywhere a \unif, \unif.

\unifinit

With a \unif, \unif{} here and a \unif, \unif{} there\\
\unif, \unif; \unif, \unif,\\
everywhere a \unif, \unif.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, LOL!  Perfect analogy.